# Zynq PS_7 to SD card write

Tags: fpga, sd-card, zynq, hardware-interface, hardware

I am trying to understand how this data can be written to a SD, mounted on Sd card slot available in enclustra PM3 boards. I am using a ZYNQ PS7. [image]

So is the above setting enough? any help is appreciated.

I am trying to write digital data using XADC on to this SD card.

Answer (score 0):

My SD config is slightly different.
[image]

Edit:
I am sorry that was the wrong Zynq config.
Here is the right part for Mars PM3.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. Is your config working? i see you have selected the Bank 1 voltages to 1.8V LVCMOS. and speed is set to slow. with few disabled and 1 enabled pull up. Can you may be explain as to how to use this? I am trying to understand the whole writing the output to an SD card.

Comment: Sorry that was the wrong Zynq board config.
I updated the config to PM3 board.
We create the u-boot/kernel/devicetree with Petalinux and use another Linux distribution.
Therefore I can not recommend how to use baremetal.